extracting substring from string in pandas
I want to extract the substring from the string column in panda dataframe. I want to discard the last 7 characters from each string.
eg:
  df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['abdfd7824Fuy','dfsfeere5424Fuy','iureiur5424Fuy'],'date2' : ['20-May-2024','20-May-2024','10-May-2024']})

expected output:
               abdfd   dfsfeere iureiur


Do you want a single string as output or a new column? Also please clarify the exact expected logic (I'm assuming you want the leading part before the digits)

Assuming you want the part before the digits, you can use str.extract with the ^(\D+) regex:
df1['new'] = df1['Name'].str.extract(r'^(\D+)', expand=False)

Output:
              Name        date2       new
0     abdfd7824Fuy  20-May-2024     abdfd
1  dfsfeere5424Fuy  20-May-2024  dfsfeere
2   iureiur5424Fuy  10-May-2024   iureiur

If you want to output a single string:
print(' '.join(df1['Name'].str.extract(r'^(\D+)', expand=False)))

Output: abdfd dfsfeere iureiur
regex demo

I actually just realized you wanted to remove the last 7 characters (I misread), then you probably just need df1['new'] = df1['Name'].str[:-7] / print(' '.join(df1['Name'].str[:-7]))

@mona please clarify if you want a new column or a single string, I might delete my answer if this is for a new column (this is already covered in the duplicate)
